# how would i get <246.64260, 167.12500, 24.62500> in to separates variables?

Tags: php

if i have `<246.64260, 167.12500, 24.62500>` each number can be from 1 to 256. I need to get it in to $X as 246, $Y as 167 and $Z as 24

How would i do this? I was thinking to remove all the spaces and them explode to get

X 246.64260

Y 167.12500

Z 24.62500

then explode again to get
X 246
Y 167
Z 24

Is this the best way of doing this?

Comment: `<246.64260, 167.12500, 24.62500>` is a string value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to blow your mind and do it really easily in one line (two if you count the string):

```
$str = '<246.64260, 167.12500, 24.62500>';
list( $X, $Y, $Z ) = array_map( 'intval', explode( ',', trim( $str, '<>' ) ) );
```

This will [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) off the leading GT and LT characters, then [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the numbers into an array using the commas. [Leading whitespace (surprisingly) doesn't matter with intval](http://codepad.org/31TwvkbA) so it is simply mapped to the separated array and then the results are [separated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) into the `$X`, `$Y`, and `$Z` variables you asked for.

Answer (score 7):

```
$input  = '<246.64260, 167.12500, 24.62500>';
$output = str_replace(array('<','>',' '), '', $input);
$output = explode(',', $output);
$output = array_map('intval', $output);

list($X, $Y, $Z) = $output;
```

Comment: `@Martin` Thanks ;)
Of course you can do it in less lines - I made it in 5 lines to make it clear :)

Comment: Coff `list($a,$b,$c) = array_map("floatval",explode(",",trim($input,"<>")));` and you should be using `floatval`

Answer (score 3):

```
$string  = '<246.64260, 167.12500, 24.62500>';
$str_esc = str_replace(array('<','>',' '), '', $string );
$output = explode(',', $str_esc);
$output = array_map('intval', $output);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
```

reference

1. [array_map](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
2. [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '<246.64260, 167.12500, 24.62500>';
$str = substr(1, strlen(trim($str)) - 1);

$array = explode(',' , $str);
$array = array_map('intval', $array);

list($X, $Y, $Z) = $array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient method, but you could use preg_match_all to put the truncated integer values into a 2D array and move it into X, Y and Z from there.

So something like:

```
$input = "<246.64260, 167.12500, 24.62500>";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+", $input, $matches);
$x = $matches[0][0];
$y = $matches[1][0];
$z = $matches[2][0];
```